# How to use using for alias?

Tags: c++, alias, typedef, using, visual-studio-2013

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using uchar = unsigned char;

int main() {
    cin.get();
}
```

This code results in error: `syntax error : missing ';' before '='`

How do I fix this (other than using `typedef`)? Doesn't Visual Studio 2013 support C++11?

Comment: Using aliases are coming in the RTM version later this year.

Comment: @chris Sum's up pretty much everything. For the rest of our fellow readers, **don't even think writing an answer based on #define**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio does not support *all* of C++11 yet. For specific parts of C++11, you can see [Herb Sutter's conformance roadmap for Visual C++](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2013/06/28/cpp-conformance-roadmap.aspx). There you can see that using aliases are planned for VS2013 RTM

Until then you will have to resort to the good old `typedef`